# A Logical Equivalence?

Tags: logic

Is $\exists y \forall x (P(y) \ \wedge (P(x) \Rightarrow (x=y)))$ the same as $\exists x \forall (y\neq x) (\neg P(y) \wedge P(x))$? I think they are, but I can't think of a way to transform from one to the other.

Comment: Is that better? I added something too. I was trying to say there exists one and only one.

Answer (score 1):

The two sentences are not equivalent. For consider the structure $M$ which has two distinct elements $a$ and $b$, and where (the interpretation of) $P$ in $M$ holds at $a$ but not at $b$.

Then the sentence $\exists y \forall x (P(x) \ \wedge (P(x) \Rightarrow (x=y)))$ is  false in $M$. But the sentence $\exists x \forall (y\neq x) (\neg P(y) \wedge P(x))$ is true in $M$.

**Edit:** The first sentence has now been edited to $\exists y \forall x (P(y) \ \wedge (P(x) \Rightarrow (x=y)))$.  With that change, the two sentences are logically equivalent. We use the semantic approach, showing that in any structure $M$, the first sentence is true if and only if the second is. That is straightforward. For each sentence is true if and only if $M$ has precisely one element $a$ such that $P(a)$ is true.
One can also use a purely syntactic approach to show equivalence. I prefer semantic.

Comment: Crap I meant to write P(y), not P(x).

Comment: I needed to work with what I saw. But if you modify the sentence or sentences, I can add to the answer.

Comment: Is it true if it is $\exists y \forall x (P(y) \ \wedge (P(x) \Rightarrow (x=y)))$. I'll change it to what I meant.

Comment: The sentences are now equivalent. We can either use a "model-theoretic" (semantic) argument, by showing both are true if and only if there is precisely one $a$ such that $P(a)$ is true. Or else we can use syntactic manipulation. I prefer the semantic.

Comment: Could you append that to your answer?

Comment: Actually, what *is* the syntactic method? How would we go about it?

Comment: First for clarity interchange roles of $x$ and $y$ in the second sentence. Then replace $\forall(x\ne y)A$ by $\forall x((x\ne y)\rightarrow A)$. Then replace $(x\ne y)\rightarrow A$ by $\lnot A\rightarrow (x=y)$, and do some minor "boolean" manipulation.